# How to add <picture> tag in Sitecore rich text editor

Tags: richtext-editor

My requirement is to customize `Rich Text` so that when an image is added to RTE, the image tag gets converted into a picture element
example :
**Image tag**

to

**picture tag**

so that responsive images in Sitecore `rich text editor`

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with some customizations. Follow these steps and try to update the OOTB logic.

Open the `InsetImage` Dialog `XML` using this path

```
wwwroot\<your-site-root>\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\InsertImage\InsertImage.xml
```

You will see on this file that the code is written in `Sitecore.Client` DLL. Here is the reference.

```
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.InsertImage.InsertImageForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

When you extract the `DLL` and go to `InsertImageForm` class, you will find the code writtn on `OnOK` method like below.

```
MediaUrlBuilderOptions shellOptions = MediaUrlBuilderOptions.GetShellOptions();
shellOptions.Language = this.ContentLanguage;
string text = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["AlternateText"]) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["AlternateText"] : mediaItem.Alt;
Tag image = new Tag("img");
this.SetDimensions(mediaItem, shellOptions, image);
image.Add("Src", MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, shellOptions));
image.Add("Alt", StringUtil.EscapeQuote(text));
image.Add("_languageInserted", "true");
if (this.Mode == "webedit")
{
SheerResponse.SetDialogValue(StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(image.ToString()));
base.OnOK(sender, args);
}
else
SheerResponse.Eval("scClose(" + StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(image.ToString()) + ")");
this.SaveFolderToRegistry();
```

You need to override this method and then update your new Class and DLL reference in the `InsertImage.xml` file.

And it should work.

Refer this article for similar kind of customization.

https://aldrichdev.wordpress.com/2017/03/21/creating-a-dynamic-image-in-rich-text-fields/